# Sharing .xlsm files with connection to Microsoft SQL Server by query used in Power Query source and password authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerquery

Inside the .xlsx file, I made a new query from the SQL Server database. I provided authentication data to the database on the internal network server and the content of the SQL query querying the tables. From my computer, the "refresh all" option performs the query to the database correctly, and then joins the data between the result table and the pivot table in the second sheet.

When sending a file to a user using the same network, I lose database connection. Is there a solution to send an .xlsm file with a saved login and password, so as not to send the .odc connection file separately and configure the connection from scratch? So-called batteries included.